Help rescue funds: Sent USDC on ETH instead of USDC on Base
I accidentally sent USDC on ETH instead of USDC on Base to a Base Safe wallet. Is there any way to recover the funds? I have already seen this video https://share.zight.com/z8uBKZYr and spoken to support.
They informed "Your safe in Base network has a different proxy factory from the ones in ETH mainnet". They suggested someone in the forum had recovered it and might be able to help.
If there is someone who can help out, I would be extremely grateful.

I suggest you still follow the steps shown in the video, which are:

Check that this proxy factory exists on Base
If yes deploy a Safe there using the method showed in the video

Please let us know if it worked, as you might need to use Safe CLI to recover your funds once your safe has been deployed, as explained here.
Hope it helps; Louis

The proxy factories for Base and Eth are different right?
Base: 0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC
ETH Mainnet: 0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2.
So how do I go about it?

Simply use the address of the one on Ethereum but on Base (0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2).
